# Update app data from server (Swift)

Tags: php, client-server, swift2

I need some help with refreshing data. I have an app in Swift 2.0 and I want to the server send an action and execute a method in the app. I already try with push notification and It works greate but if the user disable the notification the method still execute? and according my knowledge this method is only execute when you press the notification. What is the best way to acomplish this?

I am trying to avoid that the app constantly request data from the server.

My server is in PHP.

Thanks!

Comment: Manual update button

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use protocols/delegates.
Delegates are good ways to be notified only when needed and and alternative to notifications.
Go check for more here :

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Protocols.html

Answer (score 0):

With this scenario I think we have these locations to request for updates:

1. At appDelegate, overriding applicationDidBecomeActive, called when the app becomes active in foreground.
2. In the view didAppear from the main view from our app (the first view that appears when we open our app).

Both options make more requests to the server than they should, but maybe the 1st is the least costly because is called just when app becomes active, and this is a good moment to check for updates.